# switching from probability to classification while maintaining exact ORs

Tags: machine-learning, logistic, simulation, odds-ratio

I am trying to create a database with a dichotomized dependent variables and a bunch of binary (1/0) independent variables. I'd like to pre-set some associations between the independent variables and the outcome. Doing so is relatively easy - after generating the random binary covariates, I run a binomial function to predict the outcome, where I set the #number_of_test to (1) and the probability of an event to expit(b0+b1var1+b2var2.....), where b0=frequency of the outcome in the none-exposed, and b1,b2,....=my pre-specified odds ratio for each covariate.

What I realize however is that the prespecified ORs are never fully retrievable when I then run a simple GLM model on the final simulated data. This makes sense, since the process of switching from a probability of having the outcome (which is de-facto what I simulate with the equation above) to a dichotomized 1/0 variable has some randomness to it.  So when I set the OR I do so on the probability scale. But when I then use the predicted probability to create the classification 1/0 variable - I introduce some randomness. All of this means that for each database I would generate, the obtained ORs are close to the ones I a-priori defined, but not exact.

Does that mean that there is never really a way to retrieve a prespecified OR from a single simulated database? I completely understand that one way here would be simulate the data many times and run the GLM on each simulated database – on average the prespecified ORs should be obtained. But is there a way to ensure one gets the correct/prespecified ORs with only one simulated database?

Comment: there is no way for *all* numbers - because of the existence of irrational numbers. if probability is 1/3 (rational) then you just triplicate input with 0 twice and 1 once as output. there are some (infinite!) numbers that can't be written *exactly* as a fraction,  irrationals, eg (pi -3) as proper fraction.

Comment: thank you! although I'm not sure I understand you comment. The issue is not about rational/irrational numbers, but rather how to switch from a probabilistic framework to classification while maintaining the prespecified ORs.

Comment: I explained in the comment, and @Eoin has given you a worked example. rather than randomly generating 1's and 0s you just create exactly the number of 1s and zeros that will give you the same OR. so odds ratio of 1/2 = probability of 1/3 you just create 3 rows one with target 1 and 2 rows with target 0 ( or 100 rows and 200 rows etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can never get **exactly** the prespecified odds-ratio, but you can get arbitrarily close to it by setting the number of `1`s and `0`s in the outcome column for each cell in the design to match the proportion predicted by your intended odds-ratios (rounded to the nearest whole number). This eliminates any mismatch due to random simulation. The mismatch due to rounding shrinks as `n_per_cell` increases.

```r
library(tidyverse)
b0 = -1
b1 = .5
b2 = -2
n_per_cell = 1000 # Number of repetitions per cell

# There are 2 (x1) * 2 (x2) * 2 (outcomes) possible cells in this design
count_df = expand_grid(
  x1 = c(0, 1),
  x2 = c(0, 1),
  outcome = c(0, 1),
  n_total = n_per_cell
) %>%
  mutate(log_odds_outcome = b0 + b1 * x1 + b2 * x2,
         p_outcome = plogis(log_odds_outcome),
         n = ifelse(outcome == 1, 
                    round(p_outcome * n_total),
                    round((1 - p_outcome) * n_total)))
count_df
#> # A tibble: 8 × 7
#>      x1    x2 outcome n_total log_odds_outcome p_outcome     n
#>   <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>            <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     0     0       0    1000             -1      0.269    731
#> 2     0     0       1    1000             -1      0.269    269
#> 3     0     1       0    1000             -3      0.0474   953
#> 4     0     1       1    1000             -3      0.0474    47
#> 5     1     0       0    1000             -0.5    0.378    622
#> 6     1     0       1    1000             -0.5    0.378    378
#> 7     1     1       0    1000             -2.5    0.0759   924
#> 8     1     1       1    1000             -2.5    0.0759    76


# Expand the counts out into a full data frame
df = count_df %>% 
  select(x1, x2, outcome, n) %>% 
  uncount(n)
head(df)
#> # A tibble: 6 × 3
#>      x1    x2 outcome
#>   <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1     0     0       0
#> 2     0     0       0
#> 3     0     0       0
#> 4     0     0       0
#> 5     0     0       0
#> 6     0     0       0

# Look at cell means
df %>% group_by(x1, x2) %>% summarise(mean(outcome))
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'x1'. You can override using the `.groups`
#> argument.
#> # A tibble: 4 × 3
#> # Groups:   x1 [2]
#>      x1    x2 `mean(outcome)`
#>   <dbl> <dbl>           <dbl>
#> 1     0     0          0.269 
#> 2     0     1          0.0470
#> 3     1     0          0.378 
#> 4     1     1          0.0760

# Confirm log-odds-ratios are close to [-1, .5, -2]
m = glm(outcome ~ x1 + x2, data = df, family = binomial)
summary(m)
#> 
#> Call:
#> glm(formula = outcome ~ x1 + x2, family = binomial, data = df)
#> 
#> Deviance Residuals: 
#>     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
#> -0.9748  -0.7913  -0.3970  -0.3110   2.4711  
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
#> (Intercept) -1.00079    0.06726  -14.88  < 2e-16 ***
#> x1           0.50366    0.08624    5.84 5.21e-09 ***
#> x2          -2.00390    0.10507  -19.07  < 2e-16 ***
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> (Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)
#> 
#>     Null deviance: 3918.6  on 3999  degrees of freedom
#> Residual deviance: 3407.6  on 3997  degrees of freedom
#> AIC: 3413.6
#> 
#> Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 5
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you Eoin! and I'm guessing based on this that there is no way to somehow also incorporate different predefined frequencies for the covariates in this design? I.e. that X1 will be 1 for 10% of the observation, X2 for 30%, etc.? Since the prevalence of each covariate will now essentially be dictated by the intended odds-ratios (i.e. 'n' in your example above)

Comment: Actually, the odds ratio is independent of the frequency of the covariates, so you can have whatever prevalence you want. In my code, you would do this by making `n_total` depend on `x1` and `x2`, rather than being constant.

Comment: could you show me how you would modify the code for this?

Answer (score 1):

> Does that mean that there is never really a way to retrieve a prespecified OR from a single simulated database?

Yes, you will not be able to exactly identify the prespecified ORs that were used to simulate the data when you fit a logistic regression model because, as you say, the data is generating process you use includes randomness processes.

As the sample size of your simulated data set increases, the fitted ORs (estimates of your prespecified ORs) will become closer to the prespecified ORs. The confidence intervals for or estimated ORs will show you how much uncertainty there is in the estimates.